# Why I keep getting 401 Unauthorized error when trying to login with Laravel basic Auth?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication

I need an explanation for this behavior on Laravel's basic authentication.
First thing I have a seeder class with factory file to generate users.

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

I tried to log in using the user details extracted from my database using PHPMyAdmin
[image]

Here's my authentication middleware call:
[image]

Also, I tried to create a new user directly via PHPMyAdmin, But whenever I tried to log in I got the `401 Unauthorized`

I'm building an API and trying to log in using Postman and I have a clean Laravel 7 installation, and yes I know I'm entering the email as username and the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do your factory using `'password' => Hash::make('password')`

As you can see in the doc, https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/hashing#introduction 
Laravel is using BCrypt by default to generate the password hash

If you really need to create the Hash manually, head over to https://bcrypt-generator.com/ and copy the hash generated there (by default Laravel uses 12 rounds)

Comment: I'll try, but do you have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: some more details added, hope that helps 

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot, @Christophe yes it is. will give you upvote but I reached the daily limit.

Comment: No worries, be a part of the community and keep coding - that's all that matters 